# Navigate terminal scrollback using keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

On most (all?) Linux terminals (eg gnome terminal, tilda, guake etc,..) and the virtual consoles you can browse up through the terminal's scrollback buffer using the keys (ie without the mouse).  Is this possible in OSX's terminal?

eg:

1. In Gnome Terminal you enter `ls`
2. oops - 50 lines of output on a 48 line terminal
3. Ctrl-Shift-UpArrow scrolls back to see the first few lines of input (and eventually your command invocation

On VC's switch UpArrow for `PageUp` - is there anything equivalent on OSX?

I'm using OS 10.10.5

Comment: Which OS version are You using?

Comment: Version 10.10.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are shortcuts for Page Up/Down and Line Up/Down in Terminal. You can find them under **View** menu item. For Page Up press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇞ Page Up</kbd>, for Line Up press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇞ Page Up</kbd>.

Edit: you can get <kbd>⇞ Page Up</kbd> on Macbook by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑ Up Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks - turns out TotalTerminal/Visor was preventing me from seeing the View menu - otherwise I might have found it myself.  For me <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> is needed for Line Up - apparently I didn't find it due to fixation with shift.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Terminal supports the standard OS X Page Up/Down keys for scrolling by pages, and there are Terminal-specific commands for scrolling the terminal view by pages or by lines, and they have keyboard shortcuts that are available even when the terminal keyboard map binds other actions to Page Up/Down. The exact shortcuts depend on the version. See the **View** menu in recent versions, and the **Window** menu in older versions.

Comment: Hmm,... turns out half my problem seems to be that Visor prevents the terminal menu from showing,...

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of macOS you can use CMD + up/down to jump to the declaration of the previous command.

It scrolls the output to where the command was used, and is briefly highlighted above its output.